# Dashboard with auto-updating current and previous month in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I'm working on a dashboard in Tableau desktop and I want it to automatically update for the current and previous month, each month to show % change in simple, numerical terms (not graphed).

Is there a way to fix the previous month and current month numbers?

Comment: Sound like all you need is to use Relative Date filters. https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/filtering_add_dragfields_dates.html

Comment: Well that was easy! Thanks so much.

Comment: i've added this as the answer if you could mark it so. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sound like all you need is to use Relative Date filters. https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/filtering_add_dragfields_dates.html